# BCrypt: Empty Encoded Password with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, bcrypt

**A CODE SAMPLE TO HELP FIX THE PROBLEM**: https://github.com/Suwappertjes/SpringSample

**Problem**

When trying to implement jwt-security in a Spring Boot application, I run into the following problem:

When I try to login with **x-www-form-urlencoded** through Postman I get a **"Bad client credentials"** error, whilst I know the credentials to be correct.

When I look in my log, I see that **BCrypt** gave a **"Empty Encoded Password" warning**. This is odd, considering I see correctly encrypted passwords in the database when I look at it through the MySQL interpreter.

**Info**

I am using Hibernate to build a MySQL database.

compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.6.RELEASE'

compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.10.RELEASE'

compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

Java 1.8.0_212

**What I tried**

Before starting to implement security, the controllers, repositories, and MySQL database were all functioning correctly.

When I search for this problem online, some people suggest it has to do with the "**loadUserByUsername**" function. But when I debug that function I notice it is **not being called at all**.

I also tried **allowing every single path in my program AND disabling crsf** 
in case it had something to do with access rights, but both didn't change anything.  `(http.requestMatchers.andMatcher("/**").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();)`

Update: When putting **NO users** in the database, I still get the same error.

**Some code:**

The loadUserByUsername method:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(userName)
            .map(user -> new User(
                        user.getUsername(),
                        user.getPassword(),
                        UserRoleAuthority.getAuthorities(user.getRoles())
                ))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown user: " + userName));

}
```

The authenticationprovider and passwordencoder:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider getAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

The signing key:

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter result = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    result.setSigningKey(signingKey);
    return result;
}
```

Adding a new user:

```
            userRepository.save(new User()
                            .withUsername("test")
                            .withPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                            .withFirst("Admin")
                            .withLast("Nator")
                            .withEmail("test@notadmin.com")
                            .withRole(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Role.Admin, Role.NotAdmin)))
            );
```

And the Http configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/iungo/*/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/iungo/system/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/iungo/**");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // We don't use this endpoint but we have to define it anyway in order to not enable web security on the whole application.
    http
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize");
}
```

And finally, my **console**:

```
2019-06-12 10:29:58.460  INFO 25207 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final}
2019-06-12 10:29:58.461  INFO 25207 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-06-12 10:29:58.532  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-06-12 10:29:58.599  INFO 25207 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-06-12 10:29:59.092  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@c30f26d'
2019-06-12 10:29:59.098  INFO 25207 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-06-12 10:29:59.382  WARN 25207 --- [           main] o.s.s.o.p.t.s.JwtAccessTokenConverter    : Unable to create an RSA verifier from verifierKey (ignoreable if using MAC)
2019-06-12 10:29:59.595  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@56a72887, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1ddba7a0, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7adbec34, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@296bfddb, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter@22ab1b8a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@54033a65, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7dfec0bc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@42734b71, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3c8dea0b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6fe9c048, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@526fc044, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@690e4b00]
2019-06-12 10:29:59.600  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/iungo/*/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1978b0d5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@69a3bf40, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3186f8f5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@a4dcede, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@760c777d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2c731a16, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2a341e3d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6556471b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@467cd4b9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3f3f554f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@d0e4972]
2019-06-12 10:29:59.603  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/authorize']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6cf3b3d7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@462f8fe9, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@24f2608b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@713497cd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@56193e3a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3c6fc4cd, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@b2e1df3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2e785b28, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@12a9e864, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4b762988]
2019-06-12 10:29:59.731  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-12 10:29:59.902  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-06-12 10:29:59.903  INFO 25207 --- [           main] nl.highway.iungomain.Application         : Started Application in 2.937 seconds (JVM running for 3.345)
2019-06-12 10:29:59.923  INFO 25207 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-06-12 10:30:12.550  INFO 25207 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-12 10:30:12.550  INFO 25207 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-12 10:30:12.554  INFO 25207 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
2019-06-12 10:30:12.632  WARN 25207 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Empty encoded password
```

Comment: have you tried with basic authentication?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you have this methid : @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) in class extending : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter

Comment: Yes, with                 `.tokenStore(tokenStore()).accessTokenConverter(jwtTokenEnhancer()).authenticationManager(authManager);` where authManger is simply `private final AuthenticationManager authManager;`

Comment: @Suwappertjes it might help to have a sample. Could you publish a sample to GitHub - I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @jzheaux That would be great! I build a small sample with the same problem. See the Readme for all extra info: https://github.com/Suwappertjes/SpringSample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using Spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE but this setup only works in 1.5.12.RELEASE. Of course downgrading is not very good practise so I will still try to get it to work with 2.1.4.

Answer (score 7):

The bug was in my code under UserPrincipal in Security, where my getters returned null.

```
public String getEmail() {
    return null;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return null;
}
```

Here is what it should be:

```
    public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add bCryptPasswordEncoder in the configureGlobal method

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I added this block of code but nothing changed unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. In my case, the cause was my CustomUserDetails class constructor, which didn't set the password to the class, so it was always null.

Credits to this anwser:
[why spring security gives empty password to password encoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397924/why-spring-security-gives-empty-password-to-password-encoder)

Answer (score 0):

I think @ghazouanbadr's solution is correct. Although, I implemented it differently in my practice project:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserService userService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    } 

    @Override // Authorization
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override // Authentication
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
   }
}
```

Be warned, I was only about a month into learning Java when I created this class. Don't remember all to much about security, so it's not my place to tell you that this is the best way to do it. Since I recall dealing with the same issue I figured  it might guide you in the right direction.