# SpringBoot Security & MongoRepository how to fetch user by username and password

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-mongodb

I have Spring boot app that uses mongo as db. I am using spring-security to secure my endpoints:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

However I would like to introduce **login** endpoint where users will be able to provide username & password. Once I have their credentials I am going to verify if such user (with this password and username) exists in mongodb. All of my attempts to retrieve the user by username and password from Mongodb failed.

My repository looks like:

```
public interface UserRepository  extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

@Query("{ 'username' : ?0 }")
User findUserByUsername(String username);

@Query("{username : ?0, password : ?1}")
User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
 }
```

method  User findUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password); always returns null even though such user exists in db.

Application starts with the following configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class AccountApplication {

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AccountApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/id/login", "/users").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,  "/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Even if I tried to comment this row:   .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
the user can not be fetched by username and password.

How I can fetch the user by username and password?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** 
I founded the solution here: [why spring security gives empty password to password encoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397924/why-spring-security-gives-empty-password-to-password-encoder)

I forgot to set Getter of password field.

Comment: why are you using a custom `JWTAuthorizationFilter` and not the built in jwt filter?

Comment: I have custom validation in terms of authorization based on role of the user for different endpoints.

Comment: Then why are you not customizing the buildt in jwtfilter

Comment: I want to put an abstraction on top of build in jwtfilter. I didn't want to change the behaviour of build in jwtfilter. Having all of my validations in separate filter will increase robustness of my app. I have additional filters, too -> based on the role of the account, based on type of the account, etc..  I don't want to put all of the validations in single (build in) filter.

Comment: no you didn't you probably didn't know about the jwtffilter until i wrote about it.

Comment: Can you provide an example in order to illustrate the best practices around jwtfilter and how it will be better than newly created filter (dedicated semantically to specific service/roles)?