# Why getting an error Empty Encoded password / password doesn't match stored value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I trying to make simple spring security authentication app, keep getting error ACCESS DENIED with password doesn't match. Everything working in order I can create user with encode(password) but unable to authenticate. I copy hereunder all classes along with log. Grateful for the help

AuthController

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody SignupRequest 
signUpRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already 
 taken!"));
    }

    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .badRequest()
                .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in 
 use!"));
    }

    // Create new user's account
    User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
            signUpRequest.getEmail(),
            encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

    Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    if (strRoles == null) {
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is 
   not found."));
        roles.add(userRole);
    } else {
        strRoles.forEach(role -> {
            switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = 
   roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new 
   RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = 
   roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new 
   RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = 
    roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new 
    RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
            }
        });
    }

    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);


 @PostMapping("/signin")

//collect credentials
 public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest 
 loginRequest){

//call authentication
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new 
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), 
            loginRequest.getPassword()));

    
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) 
   authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new ResponseEntity<>("User has been logged in successfully", 
   HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

LoginDto

```
public class LoginRequest {
   private String username;
   private String password;
}
```

SecurityConfig (config file)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws 
Exception {
    
authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}
```

UserDetailsImpl

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String username;
private String email;

@JsonIgnore
private String password;

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String email, String password,
                       Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user){
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new UserDetailsImpl(
            user.getId(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities
    );
  }
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " 
+ username));
    return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
}
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String email;
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Error log

```
2022-01-24 15:09:06.504  INFO 12284 --- [           main] com.kash.app           
: Starting app using Java 11.0.12 on LAPTOP-BQ48GM36 with PID 12284 
 (B:\spring\bankingapp\target\classes started by The see in B:\spring\app)
2022-01-24 15:09:06.508  INFO 12284 --- [           main] com.kash.appp           
: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-24 15:09:07.352  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in 
DEFAULT mode.
2022-01-24 15:09:07.425  INFO 12284 --- [           main] .s.d 
r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 61 ms. Found 
2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-01-24 15:09:08.538  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
 2022-01-24 15:09:08.554  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-24 15:09:08.555  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-01-24 15:09:08.674  INFO 12284 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       
 : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-24 15:09:08.674  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization 
completed in 2083 ms
2022-01-24 15:09:08.919  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: 
default]
2022-01-24 15:09:08.972  INFO 12284 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    
: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.4.Final
2022-01-24 15:09:09.165  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations 
{5.1.2.Final}
2022-01-24 15:09:09.327  INFO 12284 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       
: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-01-24 15:09:09.744  INFO 12284 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       
: HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-01-24 15:09:09.766  INFO 12284 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            
: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2022-01-24 15:09:10.568  INFO 12284 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       
: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-01-24 15:09:10.577  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for 
persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-24 15:09:10.629  WARN 12284 --- [           main] 
JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. 
Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure 
spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-01-24 15:09:11.243 DEBUG 12284 --- [           main] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] 
for Ant [pattern='/logout']
2022-01-24 15:09:11.245 DEBUG 12284 --- [           main] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] 
for ExactUrl [processUrl='/login?logout']
 2022-01-24 15:09:11.245 DEBUG 12284 --- [           main] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] 
for Ant [pattern='/api/**', GET]
2022-01-24 15:09:11.245 DEBUG 12284 --- [           main] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] 
 for Ant [pattern='/api/auth/**']
 2022-01-24 15:09:11.245 DEBUG 12284 --- [           main] 
 edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression 
 [authenticated] for any request
 2022-01-24 15:09:11.257  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
 o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with 
[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFil
ter@3741071d, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@9c5d76b, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@44428583, 
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@43cc7951, org.s 
ringframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@40416321, 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@54780c40, 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2d1f3639, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@351d726c, 
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1e160a9e, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@516155b5, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@634d3439]
 2022-01-24 15:09:11.699  INFO 12284 --- [           main] 
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with 
context path ''
2022-01-24 15:09:11.708  INFO 12284 --- [           main] com.kash.BankingappApplication           
: Started BankingappApplication in 5.731 seconds (JVM running for 6.43)
2022-01-24 15:09:18.434  INFO 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       
: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-24 15:09:18.435  INFO 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        
: Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-24 15:09:18.436  INFO 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        
 : Completed initialization in 1 ms
 2022-01-24 15:09:18.446 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        
 : Securing POST /api/auth/signin
2022-01-24 15:09:18.452 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:18.455 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous 
SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:18.455 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 
 C566B70A5D0C20B95470700CB2C54501
 2022-01-24 15:09:18.461 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [POST 
   /api/auth/signin] with attributes [permitAll]
 2022-01 -24 15:09:18.461 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        
 : Secured POST /api/auth/signin
2022-01-24 15:09:58.712  WARN 12284 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        
  : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper 
 delta=48s855ms565µs700ns).
   Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.email as email2_2_, user0_.password as 
   password3_2_, user0_.username as username4_2_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=?
  Hibernate: select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_1_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_1_0_, 
  role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join roles 
 role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
  2022-01-24 15:09:58.966  WARN 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Empty encoded password
2022- 1-24 15:09:58.966 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not 
match stored value
2022-01-24 15:09:59.295  WARN 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        
: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [313] 
milliseconds.
2022-01-24 15:09:59.297 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        
: Saved request http://localhost:8088/api/auth/signin to session
2022-01-24 15:09:59.297 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher 
 [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2022-01-24 15:09:59.297 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@1c4addba
2022-01-24 15:09:59.298 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:59.298 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:59.298 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-01-24 15:09:59.300 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        
 : Securing POST /error
2022-01-24 15:09:59.300 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:59.300 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous 
SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:59.300 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        
: Secured POST /error
2022-01-24 15:09:59.314 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
a.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator : filter invocation [/error] denied for 
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], 
Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 
SessionId=807AB1236A3C173667C6CB3049D650BC], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]

 org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) 
~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
~ 
 [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~ 
 [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-01-24 15:09:59.314 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2022-01-24 15:09:59.314 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
 2022-01-24 15:09:59.314 DEBUG 12284 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: Where are you creating your users?

Comment: I make it directly in Controller.  I've just updated AuthController, you can find registerUser method under ("Signup"). I

Comment: `Empty encoded password` have you debugged your code and can tell us were is the password empty?

Comment: Password parsing, following is debug : this = {AuthController@10725} 
loginRequest = {LoginRequest@10727} 
 username = "kash"
 password = "12345"

Comment: Well this post saved my time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397924/why-spring-security-gives-empty-password-to-password-encoder

Comment: dur 5 I posted the same post, anyway thanks for the answer & thanks all